# vuejs : how to use v-model in a v-for and watch

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a list of debits and credits that I `fetch` from a server:

```js
const myApp = Vue.createApp({
    data(){
        return{
            debits:[],
            credits:[],
//cut
        }
    },
    methods:(
      fetch(myUrl,this.myInit)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => {
          this.credits = data.opes.credits,
          this.debits = data.opes.debits
        })
```

I display this in a a template, using `input type="text"` as contenteditable doesn't work with vue.js. Each line has an id and a content (`intitule`) and when the content is changed, I want the id **and** the content to be sent to a methods in the vuejs.app.js file. (preferably a `watch`) so on this gets sent to the server that updates the row with the relevant id with the relevant content. This is the code in the template:

```
 <div v-for="ligne in credits"
             :debits="ligne"
             :key="ligne.id" 
             class="ligne_entree"
             :id="'ligne_' + ligne.id">

<input type="text" v-model="ligne.intitule" :id="'intitule_' + ligne.id">

</div>
```

I currently do this:

```js
    watch:{
        'debits.intitule': function(value){
            console.log(watch, value)
        }
    }
```

I get no error messages. Nothing happens.

Comment: You have assigned `debits` as an array and you are trying to watch `debits.intitule`. You can use `v-on:input` or if you wont to post every keypress change to db `v-on:blur`.

Comment: also use vue-debounce to delay api requests other wise it will have lots of server calls on v-on:input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to use @input on @change

```
<template>
     <div v-for="ligne in credits"
             :debits="ligne"
             :key="ligne.id" 
             class="ligne_entree"
             :id="'ligne_' + ligne.id">

        <input type="text" @input="intitudeHandler($event, lingne.id)" v-model="ligne.intitule" :id="'intitule_' + ligne.id">

    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default{ 
     methods: {
       intitudeHandler(newValue, id){   ...do something...    }
     }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks Levy. What does `export default` stand for?

Comment: Ou, sorry.
I forgot write `<script>` before `export default {}`

That format is how looks like usual single file component in vue:

`
//Html 
<template>
   ..html tags
</template>

//Scripts
...imports 
export default { ..vue code }

//Style
<style lang="css">
..styles
</style>
`

read more in https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/single-file-components.html